# Are transmission line enclosures only good for subwoofers?

Tags: sound, speakers, diy, subwoofer, building

Very interested in building a transmission line enclosure as a DIY project.  But I'm wondering would you get good results from using reference speakers in a 2.1 design where another external subwoofer is used?

Comment: I thought the whole idea of TL is that (if you get it right;) you don't need a separate sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is long history of [Transmission line speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line_loudspeaker).

> Are transmission line enclosures only good for subwoofers?

No, They excel at bass but most are full range speakers.

I have a nice pair of DCM Timewindows, one of the first TL speakers.
They do provide great bass, (*That is probably the genesis of the design, to get great bass*) as well as crazy good imaging, sound stage.

> I'm wondering would you get good results from using reference speakers
> in a 2.1 design where another external subwoofer is used?

Sure you can use them in a 2.1 set up but weather or not you get good results is dependent on many variables and your knowledge of sound-waves.  You could set your sub-woofer crossover to carry the frequencies below what your TL speakers cut out at. If you build some you may find the bass they provide is enough for music, (*because presumably you will engineer them to your preferred specs.*) Movies/TV soundtracks may benefit from the lower sub-woofer.

Do your [Research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DIY+transmission+line+speakers&t=ffsb&ia=web), there are DIY  Audio and speaker building sites to explore.  [Diyaudio.com](https://www.diyaudio.com/)

[YouTube search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=DIY%20transmission%20line%20speakers).

[Interesting read](https://dmcropley.wordpress.com/2019/09/19/how-to-build-diy-transmission-line-speakers/) on a DIY build.

Comment: It bothers me that you'd go to all that trouble to get 'perfect' time alignment, then go & randomise it all again by adding a non-aligned sub...

Comment: @Tetsujin -  i would not.  But the OP asked so i thought i would throw that in.  Even the best TL speakers may not get him all the way down to where he wants to be. It does not have to be "non-aligned"  it can be tailored  if you wish. *I use my TL's for stereo, i have a separate A/V system with a sub*.